# Activate and close Tkinter Input GUI from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, module

I'm new to coding, so I apologize if I'm making a really dumb mistake.

I have one module (INPUT_GUI.py) that opens a window where my user can input information, then hit a submit button.

I have another module (Error_Check.py) that I want to use to look over the inputs for errors. If there is an error, it throws up a message box "You dun goofed bud" which they can close and correct their input error (INPUT_GUI frame hasn't closed yet). The Error_Check.py should run each time the submit button is clicked.

I want to call both of these modules from Input_Master.py, which I want to close the INPUT_GUI frame if there were no errors.

Right now, when I run the Input_Master, I don't get anything. I've got a print command in there to show me the values it grabs from the Input GUI, but I just see a 0.

What am I doing wrong?

GUI_INPUT.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

Input_Table = 0

def retrieve(): #returns the input values as a dictionary

global Input_Table
Input_Table={1:[inputA1.get(),inputB1.get()],2:[inputA2.get(),inputB2.get()]....}
return(Input_Table)

def Close_Input():
root.destroy()

def Input_Table_Gen():
root=Tk()

frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack(fill=x)
frame2=Frame(root)
frame2.pack(fill=x)
#...
frame11=Frame(root)
frame11.pack(fill=x)

inputA1=Entry(frame1,width=20)
inputA1.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

inputB1=Entry(frame1,width=20)
inputB1.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
#...
inputA10=Entry(frame1,width=20)
inputA10.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

inputB10=Entry(frame1,width=20)
inputB10.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

Submit_Button = Button(frame11,text="Submit",command=retrieve)
Submit_Button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Error_Check.py:

```
From GUI_INPUT import retrieve
x = {}
def Input_Errors(x)
#checks for errors, returns True if errors are found, and False if no errors are found
```

Input_Master.py:

```
import GUI_INPUT
from Error_Check import Input_Errors

GUI_INPUT.Input_Table_Gen

Error_Output = Error_Check.Input_Errors(Input_Table)

if Error_Output = True:
messagebox.showinfo("ERROR","You dun goofed, try again plz")
else:
GUI_INPUT.Close_Input
```

Comment: You should import your moduls `Error_Check` and `Input_Master` into your main file `GUI_INPUT`, where you define the tkinter frame and not the other way around. Then try to call the functions from there.

Comment: I'm trying to centralize the program, using a functional 'Main' to call the sub-modules. I can see the wisdom in running the Error_Check out of the GUI, and just returning an error free Input_Table, but I need to be able to 'activate' the input GUI from another module.

Comment: Ok so I think your question is not very specific. Maybe you can try to figure out as much as possible and then ask specific questions. Also you should provide a minimal reproducable example. From your code snippets it is very difficult to follow.
I have some general tips: Every tkinter widget should be in ONE file. You can make a function to get the input and then pass it to another file as argument etc. But you can not pass widgets, like buttons or entry widgets directly. For example your `messagebox.showinfo()` won't work outside the main file, because messagebox is not defined.
Good luck!